# Android parent Navigation Drawer for all activities

Tags: android, inheritance, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I am creating an app which requires same Navigation Drawer for all activities. To do so, I have created a class which extends `Activity` (need for child classes) and written the code for Navigation Drawer there.

```
public class NavigationDrawerClass extends Activity {
    String [] names = new String[]{"Rohan", "Muthu","Rishi"};
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_class);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NavigationDrawerClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                NavigationDrawerClass.this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.open_drawer ,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.close_drawer  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Drawer Closed");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("Drawer Opened");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        getActionBar().setTitle("Navigation Drawer Example");
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to extend it in some other classes eg-`public class MyActivity extends NavigationDrawerClass` but the navigation drawer is not working. Neither clicking on the drawer icon or sliding has any affect. If I try to run the `NavigationDrawerClass` as a stand alone class then it runs perfectly. What additional steps I have to take to make the navigation drawer available for all classes.

Comment: refer this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @Prag'sシ I already said, it is working when I make navigation class standalone but not working when I try to extend it in other class.

Comment: That would be the problem, then. `setContentView()` replaces whatever is currently set as the Activity's layout with the new one you specify. That is, when you call it in your extended Activities, it's clearing the DrawerLayout setup you've done in the base class.

Comment: @MikeM. so how to do it then?

Comment: @MikeM. see my comment under the valentin's answer and suggest what should I do.

Comment: One way is to remove the call to `setContentView()`, use `findViewById()` to get the DrawerLayout's content View, and inflate the extended Activity's layout and add it to the content View. If you need more specific info, you'll have to post the layouts, and maybe an example of an extended Activity (unless it's really basic).

Comment: @MikeM. It's really basic, just one `ImageView` in `activity's` layout. I am just testing so a very basic example will do. Isn't there any simple way to access activity's layout instead of inflating views in every activity?

Comment: @MikeM. drawer layout is same as that in http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. I know that I can't access View's without inflating them, I was asking for something simple, like in answer below (though not working).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the comments, in the extended Activity, we're simply finding the base class's DrawerLayout's content View, and inflating the extended Activity's layout into it.

```
public class MyActivity extends NavigationDrawerClass
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_activity, content, true);   
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fragments in your activity. This is better solution.

But if you want to extend this activity you should set layout before call super.onCreate() method. And in your layout for every extended activity must add navigation drawer.

Let' example :
In NavigationDrawerClass add method getLayout() and call in onCreate()

```
public class NavigationDrawerClass extend Activity {
      public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(getLayout());
              // your code here
      }

      protected int getLayout() {
             return R.layout.navigation_drawer_class;
      }
}
```

In child activity use code like this

```
public class YourActivity extends NavigationDrawerClass{
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate();
         // here do not call setContentView() method
         // all your other code
    }
    @Override
    protected int getLayout() {
         return R.layout.your_activity_xml_layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is working if I make the NavigationDrawerClass as the launcher class in `AndroidManifest.xml`, then the layout of `YourActivity` isn't visible. But if I try to make the `YourActivity` as the launcher class then the app crashes due to `setContentView` not working and hence all the views are set as `null`.

Answer (score 1):

An cleaner solution to @MikeM's solution is to override `setContentView` on the base class and do the trick there:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
{
    super.setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_class);

    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, content, true);
}
```

Then, on the activities that extends on, just call `setContentView` normally:

```
setContentView(R.layout.other_class);
```

**EDIT:**
Also, on the base class, is necessary to do the initialization of the drawer, drawer toggle, etc. on the `onPostCreate` method instead on `onCreate`, to avoid calling `setContentView` two times (on the base `onCreate` and on the extended class `onCreate`):

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NavigationDrawerClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            NavigationDrawerClass.this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.open_drawer ,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.close_drawer  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Drawer Closed");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Drawer Opened");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
public class MyDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
protected RelativeLayout fullLayout;
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
@Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
    fullLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mydrawer, null);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, frameLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(fullLayout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout3);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), menuItem.getTitle().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.drawer_5_reasons).setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/drawer_framelayout">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
android:background="#fefefd" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

for use:

```
public class yourclass extends MyDrawer {
```

main problam .setOnItemClickListener

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<FrameLayout>
    your main content stuff here
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<FrameLayout>
    your main content stuff here(.setOnItemClickListener)
```