# navigation drawer not opening after create a BaseActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I created a BaseActivity to open menu in many activities:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

and my BaseActivity:

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public DrawerLayout nDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);


        nDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, nDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        nDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        NavigationView view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.nav_upload:
                        Intent upIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, Upload.class);
                        BaseActivity.this.startActivity(upIntent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        Intent logIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        BaseActivity.this.startActivity(logIntent);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

xml base_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.sk.mf.BaseActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@layout/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

xml navigation_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/menuitens">

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_upload"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_file_upload_black_24dp"
        android:title="Upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</menu>
```

When I click on the navigation drawer icon, nothing happens. It occurs after I create the BaseActivity. what is wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you have any other code in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @MikeM. not for navigation drawer, just other things from mainactivity activities!

Comment: Right, like what, exactly? How are you adding `MainActivity`'s layout stuff, for example?

Comment: usually a `recyclerView` things and some others like `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`, `addOnScrollListener`... @MikeM.

Comment: Yep, that's it. As soon as you call `setContentView()` in `MainActivity`, it completely replaces the layout you set in `BaseActivity`. That is, you don't have a drawer anymore.

Comment: @Rick Because **you need 2 child Views** in `DrawerLayout`? in your case you only have `NavigationView`.

Comment: oh, so what should I do now to make it work? ;/

Comment: Something like this `<DrawerLayout> <LinearLayout....></LinearLayout> <NavigationView..></NavigationView></DrawerLayout>` . In this example it has 2 child views namely `LinearLayout` and `NavigationView`. Note: the NavigationView should come second and do not interchange them.

Comment: There's a couple examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842615/android-parent-navigation-drawer-for-all-activities

Comment: @MikeM. thank! just one more question, I don't understand what shoud I add at: ` ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);` what is `R.id.content_frame` in my example?

Comment: That would be the second `View` that @Enzokie talking about. You need an empty `ViewGroup` in the `DrawerLayout`, listed before the `NavigationView`, to act as the content holder. You could just stick a `FrameLayout` there, give it that ID, and then you'll be inflating `MainActivity`'s layout into that, instead of calling `setContentView()` there again. Follow me?

Comment: @MikeM. oh, I will try that. thank you!

Comment: it works! thank you friends!